# Event listener fires 2 functions at the same time but partially

Tags: javascript, json, function, httprequest, eventhandler

I am making a list where you can edit or delete items. I am listening for 2 events on the same table. One for edit and one for delete, I am listening on the table and not the actual buttons as they are created dynamically. Edit and Delete both have the same id, the id of the product, which I am using later for the http requests.

Now when I press edit the console.logs from the delete functions fire up,but nothing happens, if I am trying to save the item the http request doesn't work, it will not take the id (but it logs it to the console)

If I press the delete button once nothing happens, if I press it a second time the page refreshes and the item is deleted.

Is there a way to listen for those events separately or for them to not interfere with one another? All I want is if I press the edit button the respective item's values to go to the input field and when I press Add Item update the product in the JSON file as well, and on delete press, to delete the item from the JSON file and remove from the html document.

Update: Managed to resolve edit function

Here is my code:

```js
import { http } from "./http.js";
import { ui } from "./ui.js";

const productsURL = "https://61363d1a8700c50017ef54c1.mockapi.io/product";
// const addProductBtn = document.querySelector('.new-product-btn');
const adminContainer = document.querySelector('.admin-container');
const addItem = document.querySelector('.admin-add-item-btn');
const imgInput = document.getElementById('image');
const nameInput = document.getElementById('name');
const priceInput = document.getElementById('price');
const stockInput = document.getElementById('stock');
const categoryInput = document.getElementById('category');
const typeInput = document.getElementById('type');
const descriptionInput = document.getElementById('description');
const validSvg = document.querySelectorAll('.valid_input_svg');
// const adminForm = document.getElementById('admin-form');
const adminTable = document.getElementById('admin-tbody');
const editBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.edit-btn');
const adminBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.admin-delete-btn');
const cancel = document.getElementById('cancel');
let productToEdit;
let edit = false;
let id;


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', listAdminProducts);


// adminForm.addEventListener('submit', validateInput);
addItem.addEventListener('click', addOrEditProducts);
// adminTable.addEventListener('click', editOrDeleteItem);
adminTable.addEventListener('click', deleteProduct);
adminTable.addEventListener('click', editProduct);
cancel.addEventListener('click', cancelEdit);

function listAdminProducts() {
    http.get(productsURL).then(products => {
        ui.showAllAdminProducts(products);
    });
};


function addOrEditProducts() {
    if (edit === true && validateInput() === true) {
        productToEdit = {
            image: imgInput.value,
            name: nameInput.value,
            price: priceInput.value,
            stock: stockInput.value,
            category: categoryInput.value,
            type: typeInput.value,
            description: descriptionInput.value,
        };
        http
            .put(`${productsURL}/${id}`, productToEdit)
            .then(() => listAdminProducts());
        console.log(`${productsURL}/${id}`)
        ui.clearFields();
        id = '';
        edit = false;
        return;
    } else if (edit === false && validateInput() === true) {
        const product = {
            image: imgInput.value,
            name: nameInput.value,
            price: priceInput.value,
            stock: stockInput.value,
            category: categoryInput.value,
            type: typeInput.value,
            description: descriptionInput.value
        };
        http.post(productsURL, product).then(() => listAdminProducts());
        ui.clearFields();
    };
};

function editProduct(e) {
    console.log('works');
    if (e.target.classList.contains('edit-btn')) {
        edit = true;
        id = e.target.getAttribute('id');
        console.log(id);
        console.log(e.target)
        http.get(`${productsURL}/${id}`).then((data) => {
            imgInput.value = data.image;
            nameInput.value = data.name;
            priceInput.value = data.price;
            stockInput.value = data.stock;
            categoryInput.value = data.category;
            typeInput.value = data.type;
            descriptionInput.value = data.description;
        });
        console.log(`${productsURL}/${id}`)
    };
    // id = '';
}

function deleteProduct(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    if (e.target.className === 'admin-delete-btn') {
        console.log(e.target);
        id = e.target.getAttribute('id');
        console.log(id);
        http
            .delete(`${productsURL}/${id}`)
            .then(() => listAdminProducts())
            .catch("Error on delete");
        id = '';
    }
    ui.showSuccessMessage('Product deleted', adminContainer);
}

function cancelEdit() {
    ui.clearFields;
    imgInput.className = '';
    nameInput.className = '';
    priceInput.className = '';
    stockInput.className = '';
    categoryInput.className = '';
    edit = false;
}


function validateInput() {
    let valid = true;
    if (imgInput.value == '') {
        if (imgInput.classList.contains('input-invalid')) {
            imgInput.classList.remove('input-invalid');
        };
        ui.showAdminMessage('Must contain a link to an image', 0);
        imgInput.classList.add('input-invalid');
        valid = false;
    } else {
        imgInput.classList.add('input-valid');
        validSvg[0].style.display = "block";
        removeClass(imgInput, 0);
    };

    if (nameInput.value === '') {
        if (nameInput.classList.contains('input-invalid')) {
            nameInput.classList.remove('input-invalid');
        };
        ui.showAdminMessage('Name is requierd', 1);
        nameInput.classList.add('input-invalid');
        valid = false;
    } else {
        // stockInput.classList.remove('input-invalid');
        nameInput.classList.add('input-valid');
        validSvg[1].style.display = "block";
        removeClass(nameInput, 1);
    };

    if (priceInput.value == "" || isNaN(priceInput.value) || priceInput.value < 0) {
        if (priceInput.classList.contains('input-invalid')) {
            priceInput.classList.remove('input-invalid');
        };
        ui.showAdminMessage('Price must be a number greater then 0', 2);
        priceInput.classList.add('input-invalid');
        valid = false;
    } else {
        // stockInput.classList.remove('input-invalid');
        priceInput.classList.add('input-valid');
        validSvg[2].style.display = "block";
        removeClass(priceInput, 2);
    };

    if (stockInput.value == "" || isNaN(stockInput.value) || stockInput.value < 0) {
        if (stockInput.classList.contains('input-invalid')) {
            stockInput.classList.remove('input-invalid');
        };
        ui.showAdminMessage('Stock must be a number greater then 0', 3);
        stockInput.classList.add('input-invalid');
        valid = false;
    } else {
        // stockInput.classList.remove('input-invalid');
        stockInput.classList.add('input-valid');
        validSvg[3].style.display = "block";
        removeClass(stockInput, 3);
    };

    if (categoryInput.value === 'barware' || categoryInput.value === 'spirits') {
        // categoryInput.classList.remove('input-invalid');
        categoryInput.classList.add('input-valid');
        validSvg[4].style.display = "block";
        removeClass(categoryInput, 4);
    } else {
        ui.showAdminMessage('Category must be barware or spirits', 4);
        categoryInput.classList.add('input-invalid');
        valid = false;
    };
    return valid;
};

function removeClass(element, index) {
    // console.log(element, index);
    setTimeout(() => {
        element.className = '';
        validSvg[index].style.display = "none";
    }, 3000)
}
```

Comment: um, do you realize you have code outside the if statements? Like `ui.showSuccessMessage('Product deleted', adminContainer);` is going to run no matter if you click the delete button or not.

Comment: Just exit out `function deleteProduct(e) { if (!e.target.closest('.admin-delete-btn')) return;`

Comment: **Edit and Delete both have the same id**. IDs should be unique. You should put the product ID in a `data-XXX` attribute.

Comment: Yes I know that they have the same id, they have the id of the product, which i am using at the http requests, but they are reset in the functions. I will try to put the id in a data-value attribute

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to resolve it, I had to put e.preventDefault() in both functions, so the page will not reload first